# Why two terminals show different OpenGL versions?

Tags: shell, driver, qt-creator, ubuntu-20.04, qtopengl

I work on Ubuntu 20.04.

I updated graphics drivers and restarted X. I had to upgrade OpenGL since after upgrading drivers the OpenGL version was downgraded for some reason. I opened `bash` terminal and updated the drivers as described [here](https://itsfoss.com/install-mesa-ubuntu/):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Now, when I run `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"` either on terminal opened from VSCode or from Ubuntu itself it shows version 4.5.

```
user@user:~$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.1.0 - kisak-mesa PPA
```

But, when I open the terminal from Qt Creator it shows version 3.1

```
user@user:~$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 21.2.6
```

How this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Qt Creator has its own environment variables that it loads when building a project.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH` had paths to `/snap/qtcreator-.../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri` which has older graphics driver libraries than in `/usr/lib/.../dri`. When the terminal from *Qt Creator* started, it looked for drivers there and not in `/usr/lib/...` where new drivers werer installed.

Once I removed that `/snap/...` it allowed *Qt Creator* to look for OpenGL libraries in the default location `/usr/lib/...` where new dirvers where installed.